# Using Grep To Parser Openssl Output

Tags: linux, parsing, grep

Hi i know there is some other threads about grep and parsing but i tryed most of the other ways describe on the other questions and didnt work for me, i would like to parse a openssl log to a .csv and by that make the usual ; to pars the columns .

output to parse :

```
Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption

Issuer: C=PT, L=Jersey, O=UFO - UFO Solutions,
CN=UFO Software ROOT Primary CA/emailAddress=ufo@wtf.us

Validity
Not Before: Jan 24 11:10:13 2011 GMT
Not After : Jan 21 11:10:13 2021 GMT

Subject: C=US, L=Jersey, O=UFO - UFO Solutions,OU=CER, CN=UFO PSS Intermediate CA/emailAddress=ufo@wtf.us

Subject Public Key Info:
Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
RSA Public Key: (2048 bit)
```

I want to parse every word after the " = " and get the next word that have " = "
and save the result on the .csv file

the maximum i got was with this grep -E '\=' result.txt > teste.csv and i got :

```
Issuer: C=PT, CN=Teste
Subject: C=PT, CN=Teste
```

the desired result would be a csv with only the results . like:

```
sha1WithRSAEncryption, Jan 24 11:10:13 2011 GMT, Jan 21 11:10:13 2021 GMT, PT, Jersey, UFO,
```

etc.

Comment: Please indicate in your question what is your expected ouput from the example input you wrote.

Comment: i would like to parse it to get a .csv with the items like .:

Issuer CommonNAme
PT     TESTE

Comment: @drd0sPy It's still not clear, which is why you haven't got any answers so far. Please [edit] the question and add the exact desired output. What is `CommonNAme`? It's not in the input.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -oP '(?<==)\w*' result.txt
```

will do almost what you need (if your `grep` version supports Perl regex).

The output is

```
PT
Teste
PT
Teste
```

because this is the order the values appear in the input.

Comment: hi Lev, can you tell me how can i add to the results of grep for each word he parsed with your grep -oP '(?<==)\w*' result.txt add the ";" in front of that for the separation of the collums ?

Comment: @drd0sPy you can't do it with grep. It's for filtering of the input, not alternating it. Look at sed for that.

Comment: ok, this is all part of a shell script that i created so for now i made a for w in $word ... being $w your command and just added the ";" in front fo the echo $w > result.csv :D tnx

Comment: Mr.Lev can you tell me how to grab in grep command to the .csv output the :

Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
Not Before: Sep 21 11:27:02 2012 GMT

The dates and the "sha1with" singnature algorithm
Not After : May 26 11:27:02 2026 GMT

Comment: @drd0sPy Can you please edit your question again to add the output you need? It'll be easier to understand.